# В какой форме писать причастный оборот

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста. В предложении: Каждая из 62 иллюстраций, представленных на конкурс, была по- своему уникальна. В правильной ли форме написано слово "представленных", с каким словом его согласовать- "каждая" или "иллюстраций"? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждая из 62 иллюстраций, представленных на конкурс, была по-своему уникальна.
Определение относится к 62 иллюстрациям.

Сравнить: Один из тридцати выпускников, окончивших школу, получил медаль